# Starting a mock server for cucumber test for only one time

Tags: java, testing, automation, cucumber

I have a scenario where need to start a mock sftp server before running all the test cases. if I used the before and after methods for start and stop the mock server, it is getting invoked for each and every test case. So is there any way to start the server in the beginning of all test cases and stop it once all the test cases are finished.

Comment: Refer to this - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/515. Basically use a static flag for the before method and jvm shutdown hook for the after method.

Comment: Thanks for the information . It is really help full. Is it possible to pass cucumber properties to hook methods ?

Comment: You can pass the Scenario object to the after and before hooks. Cucumber will inject the currently executing Scenario to the hook method. Can you clarify what cucumber properties you are referring to?

Comment: @Jenananthan Can you tell me what is the mocksftpserver you used? any link will be helpful